# Restrict sonata_type_model_list to 1 context

Tags: sonata-media-bundle

I am trying to allow users to select from existing images in the system and have context set like the provided example and this works. How can I stop the users from selecting from any other context type?

```
$form->add('image', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(), array('link_parameters' => array('context' => 'news')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I just stumbled over the parameter: **hide_context**

```
$form->add('image', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(), array(
    'link_parameters' => array(
        'context' => 'news', 
        'hide_context' => true
     )
 ))
```

Maybe you want to give it a try?

Comment: Sounds useful. If I ever get back top that code I will try it out